# Adding User Input to a hash? Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am trying to create some simple programs as trying to learn Ruby and then move on to rails, I am just playing about to try and get used to the flow of how different types of code work variables, loops etc.

I am trying to create a simple book system were I already have 3 books in my hash and then I want to list the books already in the library in the console and then I want to be able to add new books and then also loop through and display the new list to the console.

```
require 'rubygems'

class GetDetailsFromUser
  books = {
      Eagle_Eye: 1,
      Eage_Eye1: 2,
      Eagle_Eye2: 3
  }

  books.each do |i|
    puts i
  end

  while true
    add = gets.chomp
    break if add.empty?
    books << add
  end

  puts 'New list is below'

  books.each do |i|
    puts i
  end
end
```

Were am I going wrong? I manage to print out the hash to the console, however, I get an error message

> `undefined method '<<' for {:Eagle_Eye=>1,...`

Why is the method undefined? `books << add`? This should add a new book to the book hash table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refactored version of @ExecutiveCloser

```
books = {
    Eagle_Eye: 1,
    Eage_Eye1: 2,
    Eagle_Eye2: 3
}

books.each do |i|
    puts i
end

add = ""

while add.empty? do
    puts "What book would you like to add?"
    add = gets.chomp

    books[add.to_sym] = books.size + 1 unless add.empty?
end

puts 'New list is below'

books.each do |i|
    puts i
end
```

https://repl.it/CDK2/3

Answer (score 2):

Add your second number with it. Here is a working example I wrote for you

Live Demo - [VISIT THIS LINK](https://repl.it/CDK2)

```
  books = {
      Eagle_Eye: 1,
      Eage_Eye1: 2,
      Eagle_Eye2: 3
  }


      books.each do |i|
        puts i
      end

      while true
        puts "What book would you like to add?"
        add = gets.chomp
        if add.empty? == true
            puts "Error - You did not enter a title for a book"
            break
        else
        books.max_by do |book,id|
                 @list_number = id
                end
         books[add.to_sym]=@list_number
         break
        end
      end

  puts 'New list is below'

  books.each do |i|
    puts i
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a documentation site. E. g. [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html) documentation clearly states, that there is no method `<<` defined on the hash instance.

`<<` method is defined on [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C).

Why would you expect “`books << add` should add a new book to the book hash table”?

There is another glitch within your code: you execute everything on class definition level, which makes absolutely no sense in this case.

Since it is unclear what do you want to achieve, I am unable to provide a ready-to-go-with solution.